# Как заблокировать ввод данных в QTableView и QSqlTableModel?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

> Необходимо, в таблице, запретить редактирование всех колонок, кроме
>   последней.

Я пытался найти решение, везде пишут про свой делегат. Я не очень понимаю как его сделать. Можете помочь?

```
virtual QWidget * createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override {     
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Таблица]

Comment: Везде где искал,была такая реализация, но как я понимаю она стара и не работает!

Comment: Вставляйте код текстом. С картинкой неудобно работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы запретил редактирование вставив между `QTableView` и `QSqlTableModel` свою proxy-модель. Задача «Редактировать только 10-й столбец» будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
class ModifyEditabilityModel: public QIdentityProxyModel {
public: 
    ModifyEditabilityModel (QObject * parent = 0) : QIdentityProxyModel(parent)
    {}

    Qt::ItemFlags flags (const QModelIndex & index) const {
        if (index.column() == 10) {
            return QIdentityProxyModel::flags();
        } else {
            return QIdentityProxyModel::flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable;
        }
    }
};

//...
  proxyModel = new ModifyEditabilityModel(view);
  proxyModel.setSourceModel (mySqlTableModel);
  view.setModel (proxyModel);
```

Само собой, по желанию интерфейс можно допилить до реюзабильного...

Comment: Спасибо большое!!

Answer (score 1):

Можно через делегат (не проверял):

```
virtual QWidget * createEditor(   
    QWidget *parent, 
    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, 
    const QModelIndex &index) const override 
{     
    if( index.column() < /*Cколько всего стоблцов в таблице*/ -1 )
        return 0;

    return QItemDelegate::createEditor(...);
}
```

Но лучше наследовать модель `QSqlTableModel` и переопределить единственный метод `flags`:

```
 class SqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel {
 public:
     Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) {
         Qt::ItemFlags f = QSqlTableModel::flags(index);
         if( index.column() < this->columnCount() -1 ) {
             f.setFlag(Qt::ItemIsEditable‌, false); // Выключаем флаг редактирования колонки
             f.setFlag(Qt::ItemIsEnabled, false);  // Так вообще запрещаем прикосаться к колонке
         }
         return f;
     }
 }
```

Так удобнее контроллировать данные, не вмешиваясь в отображение (делегат).
В остальном данный класс будет вести себя как и QSqlTableModel.

p.s. А еще лучше через прокси-модель, так вообще никаких изменений делать не нужно (Вылетело из головы). Такой вариант ответа уже предложен, изучайте. )